Gitlab CI/CD pipeline configuration for a multi-module spring boot project
I have a multi-module Spring boot project. I'm trying to configure GitLab's CI/CD pipe with a test job for one of the modules. Here's the job:
payroll-test:
  allow_failure: true
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - ./gradlew :payroll:test --stacktrace

Running ./gradlew :payroll:test locally works fine and the test passes, yet it fails on the pipe.
I tried adding a stacktrace but that didn't help with anything.
That's the exception GitLab is throwing:
\* Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':payroll:test'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142) at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java

I tried adding ./gradlew clean before running the test, but that didn't help either.

there should be additional information / logs available...
